# Camel intercept / marshal jms reply

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am trying to get a request/reply jms consumer in camel,
The incoming message is received and i can see that camel also sends the reply but the message is not marshaled.

I am using interceptors to marshal all messages from and to the activemq endpoint

```
OsdrDataFormat osdrDataFormat = new OsdrDataFormat();

interceptFrom("activemq:*").unmarshal(osdrDataFormat);
interceptSendToEndpoint("activemq:*").marshal(osdrDataFormat);
```

(I extend the JacksonDataFormat so i can fill the JMSType when marshalling a message.)

For normal one way exchanges this is working (e.g.)

```
from("activemq:queue:test").bean(TestComponent.class, "test");
from("direct:test-input").to("activemq:queue:test");
```

But when i use this route

```
from("activemq:queue:test").bean(TestComponent.class, "test");
```

And send a message with a JMSReplyTo message to the test queue (using the activemq management page) i can see that camel did sent the reply message but it is not marshaled to json.

Adding the marshal manually does work, but i prefer to use the interceptor as that would allow me to make a abstract RouteBuilder and add the interceptors by default to each route.

```
from("activemq:queue:test").bean(TestComponent.class, "test").marshal(osdrDataFormat);
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this? or maybe a better way to make sure that all messages from and to activemq are marshaled?

i also found this thread: [Apache Camel inOut routes, out exchange marshaling/unmarshaling with jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456807/apache-camel-inout-routes-out-exchange-marshaling-unmarshaling-with-jaxb)
but the answer here is to use the manual marshal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `interceptSendToEndpoint` is only when Camel sends a message to a Camel endpoint - not when a JMS component internally send some JMS message to some JMS destination. Its not the same.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply, i the end using the manual marshal and unmarshal was the best solution, we found some use cases where we would like to do something else before the unmarshal.